# How do I create a user.alias resource for python script

Tags: python, insert, alias

I do the following to create a user resource to do a user.insert for SDK Admin directory API in a python script:

```
userinfo = { 'primaryEmail': 'joe@xxx.yyy', 'name': { 'given_name': 'joe', 'familyName': 'smith' }, 'password': 'password' }

service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)

service.users().insert(body=userinfo).execute()

How do I similarly create a user.alias resource so that I can do something like:

userinfo = {'alias': 'js@xxx.yyy'}

service.users().alias.insert(userKey=joe@xxx.yyy, body=userinfo).execute
```

Getting:

```
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'alias' ... or variants thereof with modifications. Twisted in the syntax for "user.alias" resources.
```

Comment: I resolved as follows:   service.users().aliases().insert(userKey=joe@xxx.yyy, body=userinfo).execute

Answer (score 1):

I resolved as follows:

service.users().aliases().insert(userKey=joe@xxx.yyy, body=userinfo).execute

I had tried users().alias() ... but needed aliases().

Answer (score 0):

Here's the function I use to drop all Google email aliases and then create a set of new ones from addresses submitted in a form (Django):

```
def google_set_aliases(request, username, aliases):
    '''
    Resets the list of email aliases for a user in the Google directory.
    To ensure that LDAP is canonical, we first delete all Google aliases,
    then insert the new list. Takes `aliases` as a python list of email addresses.

    e.g. (in another function):
        aliases = ['foo@exmaple.com', 'bar@example.com']
        google_set_aliases(request, 'msmith', aliases)

    '''
    try:
        # google_get_auth() is a separate func that gets an authenticated handle on a
        # with a passed-in scope (using 2LO).
        http_auth = google_get_auth(scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.alias')
        service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http_auth)

        # Get the user's complete set of Google-stored aliases.
        google_aliases = service.users().aliases().list(userKey="{u}@example.com".format(u=username)).execute()

        # If returned set is non-empty, delete them all.
        if 'aliases' in google_aliases:
            templist = [entry['alias'] for entry in google_aliases['aliases']]
            for alias in templist:
                service.users().aliases().delete(userKey="{u}@example.com".format(u=username), alias=alias).execute()

        # Now insert new aliases. Google automatically drops existing users so we don't have to check for conflicts.
        for alias in aliases:
            service.users().aliases().insert(userKey="{u}@example.com".format(u=username), body={'alias': alias}).execute()

        return True
    except:
        return False
```